# Unity5 and Vuforia, Display 2 dimension picture as background behind camera device?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm making an android app quite like Snapchat but focusing on the background. Basically, I want to make a custom background, let's say it's a picture of snow like this

[image: example]

Then I also use Vuforia for Unity to display an augmented reality model, I'm using the ARcamera from Vuforia, I'm using `arcamera` for the 3d model, I need it to display the 3d model, I'm using lean touch asset to resize and move the model.

The problem is, how to merge the background to the device camera? So people can also be detected. Or how to make the snow background as my background in device camera?

I want the result as I can take a picture of someone in the middle of the snow background.

I'm using Unity 5.4 and Vuforia 6.2.

Comment: @Sunil Garg : I approved your edit. However, `code markdown` should only be used for code, not for product names. Also, to inline an image, you can add a "!" in front of the image link.

Comment: This is possible and its called occlusion (or mesh occlusion). So far `Vuforia` doesn't have a built in function for that.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks for the edit, appreciate it

Comment: @Hristo thanks for the reply sir, appreciate it, do you have any suggestion how to do it? i'm currently thinking making an photo editor to change the background to custom background, so after taking a photo, then you can change the background, but i still don't find anything yet

Comment: If we are talking about a still photo with people in it, you could detect faces/bodies and cut them out of the picture. Then you can place the cut-outs(people) into a different environment